# Loop adicionando valores repetidos

Tags: node.js, lógica

Eu tenho um loop dentro de um request, que adiciona um  ID em um array, para que na próxima repetição ele verifique sé este mesmo ID já não esta adicionado. e se ele ja estiver no array, pula para o proximo id do array.

```
setInterval(all, 5000);
    
    function all{
        request(html[i], function(erro,resp,html)
        {
          var data = JSON.parse(html[i]);
          if(all_id[index] != data.live_id)
          {
            all_id.push(data.live_id)
            index++
                  
          }else{
           index++
          }
        } 
    }
```

Mas por algum motivo, meu loop não esta fazendo o que quero, e acaba adicionando os mesmos valores fazendo minha verificação de ID não funcionar, como posso resolver?

[image: Na imagem da para ver o loop adicionando o valor 352919 duas vezes.]

Na imagem da para ver o loop adicionando novamente  os mesmo valores mas de traz para frente.

Comment: Por que você não busca primeiro de depois inserir se não houverEx.: `if( all_id.findIndex(data.live_id) == -1 ) all_id.push(data.live_id)`

Comment: Deu certo! Obrigado.

Comment: Que bom que deu certo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao invés de fazer assim:

```
if(all_id[index] != data.live_id){
    all_id.push(data.live_id)
    index++
 }else{
    index++
  }
```

Você a nova função [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) do javascript que caso não encontre no seu array, retorna -1, e se retornar -1 é porque não tem no seu array e então você insere

Exemplo:

```
if( all_id.findIndex(data.live_id) == -1 ) all_id.push(data.live_id)
```

Espero ter ajudado